# Is there a voice-activated command prompt?

Tags: macos, terminal, voice-dictation

I injured a hand six weeks ago, and, being a programmer/sysadmin, I'm looking into ways to control a Terminal application using my voice (or, I suppose more broadly, not using my left hand).

I am getting a feel for the built-in Mac Dictation (in OS X 10.10), but have not found it to be fruitful with terminal, even when I created advanced commands (which didn't work for me in Terminal.app).

**Has anyone had success using Mac dictation (or some other technology) for accessing the command line?**

- I am aware of [Using Python To Code By Voice](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SkdfdXWYaI) and http://voicecode.io/.  Both look very interesting.  If I knew it'd do the trick (and that my injury will take long enough to heal to warrant it), I'd come up with the money for Dragon Dictate and add-ons.  [Is there anything like [DragonFly](https://github.com/dictation-toolbox/dragonfly) that uses Mac Dictation?]
- I have briefly tried some other Terminal apps -- MacTerm in particular looks promising.